# Can MBP 16" ( Late 2019) retina screen can be replaced with non-retina non-Apple screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I am getting some lines on one end of the screen I went to Aptronix (Apple retailer in India) customer care they are saying its pressure damage. I have never dropped the laptop nor hit the screen accidentally, but there some little scratches from normal usage. They mostly likely do not want to cover me under warranty so I am searching for alternate options. I wanted to replace my etina screen with a non-retina display like some UHD screen or any other screen.

Comment: I would pursue the warrantee, either with Aptronix, or directly with Apple India, if possible.

Comment: actually, it turns out kind of physical damage there is a small crack in the screen internally so the case is out of warranty.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not practically possible.

It is of course theoretically possible, but the costs involved for a one-off would be so high that you could buy a Retina display instead at lower cost.

Comment: hey can help with me any web site where we can buy the retina display I have checked on Amazon and Flipkart i couldn't find anything